# Сервер на смартфоне

Tags: java, android, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер

Я реализовал простейший сокет-сервер. На ПК он работает, но при переносе его на android-смартфон возникли проблемы. Одну я уже решил - это необходимость прописать `android.permission.INTERNET`. Но соединение всё ещё не происходит. Есть ли какие-то нюансы ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением явилось приобрести симку с выделенным IP. Если нужно просто протестировать приложение, то можно все устройства подключить через домашний роутер. Т.о. они окажутся в одной сети и получат доступ друг к другу.

Answer (score 1):

Перед местами в коде, где происходит соединение напишите

```
val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

А так же импортируйте модуль

```
import android.os.StrictMode
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вставил этот код перед вызовом: serverClient=server.accept(). Не помогло.

Comment: Загоните в дебаггер. Дайте скриншот ошибки пожалуйста, или текстом

Comment: Так ошибки на стороне сервера нет. Программа "виснет" на запросе:  serverClient=server.accept() ожидая подключения. Но я посылаю запрос с клиента и он не доходит. На клиенте возникает ошибка: java.net.ConnectException: Время ожидания соединения истекло (Connection timed out).

Comment: Откройте дебаггер в iDE на стороне клиента. Когда программа зависнет посмотрите в консоль дебаггера. Должна быть ошибка

Comment: Уже написал, какая ошибка на клиенте. На сервере ошибки не выдаёт, и после падения клиента тоже. Он продолжает работать ожидая подключения.

Comment: Попробуйте просто отправить запрос на любой сервер с клиента

Comment: Абсолютно любой. Например val s = url("https://google.com")

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108855/discussion-between-sapeg-and-nixs-code).